# Suggestions for comprehensive maths book library

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, analysis, reference-request, differential-geometry

I've problem that I'm slowly forgetting the math I've learned in early years at university (right now I'm in final year of Mgr. degree as theoretical physicist).

I'd like to assemble a finite but comprehensive maths book library for my self. I would be glad for suggestions you can give me for rigorous books on separate topics or even complete courses (which you consider great). On other side of the spectrum some intuitive summaries such as [http://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Tools-Physics-James-Nearing/dp/048648212X/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/048648212X) would be also good...

Comment: Well price of the knowledge and it's accessibility is topic for itself and we could debate it elsewhere. I would welcome if this topic stayed at original purpose - create list of worthwile math literature for consulting and refreshing math problems from rigorous and also intuitive points of view.

Answer (score 1):

Some books listed at [Fun but serious mathematics books to gift advanced undergraduates.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264371/fun-but-serious-mathematics-books-to-gift-advanced-undergraduates) and at  [What is the single most influential book every mathematician should read?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-mathematician-should-read)

I would go for *The Princeton Companion to Mathematics* as an advanced and detailed overview